glossaries + glossaries-extra cause "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=32767]"
I have a weird error regarding the usage of the glossaries and glossaries-extra packages:
I'm using a thesis template of TU Berlin, which works totally fine on Overleaf. Now, I tried to setup VSCode locally but there the template suddenly gave a "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry" error.
I narrowed it down to the following - the problem is putting abbreviations as an option in glossaries-extra (compiling with lualatex):
\errorcontextlines=200

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\RequirePackage[toc,acronym,nomain,indexonlyfirst]{glossaries}
\RequirePackage[toc,abbreviations,nomain,indexonlyfirst]{glossaries-extra}

\begin{document}

asdf

\end{document}

Removing abbreviations from the options list makes my document compile. It seems like there is some infinite loop happening somewhere.
Any ideas why this is the case and why it compiles on Overleaf?
(My first question here, please be gentle )

I cannot reproduce your problem with the shown code using TeX Live 2022, 2023, or 2024. Only with older TeX Live, e.g., 2020 I get an error. So maybe you should update.

I can reproduce both on Overlaf and locally with TeX Live 2021/2022. With TeX Live 2023 it works fine though.

It says I'm using TexLive 2022 on my machine when I do tex --version :/

Ok, I'll try TexLive 2023 and give an update!

Why TeX Live 2023 and not TeX Live 2024, which is the current version?

Also when I remove \RequirePackage{glossaries} it works ok - maybe you don't need that one? glossaries-extra also loads glossaries.

I'll try Tex Live 2024 and regarding using only one, this came from the template and I was afraid there would be issues later if I just removed something (like some refs not showing up or so). I didn't know that glossaries-extra loads glossaries. I'll try theTexLive first since I removed the old version already and post an update. Thanks for the super quick help you two!

Welcome to TeX.SE!

It worked with the 2024 version of TexLive! And I was also able to confirm the version problems on Overleaf, just as @Marijn said.

There seems to be an issue with the TexLive versions prior to 2023 with these two packages.
Thanks to the comments by @cabohah and @Marijn I updated my TexLive version to 2024 and now everything compiles again!

Good that you solved it - we will close the question though, there is a close reason that includes "solved by an update". The question itself was quite good though, clearly described, a small complete example included, and being responsive in comments.
